# How to post a review using Yelp API?

Tags: yelp

I know we can search posted reviews on Yelp using Yelp Review Search API. Is it possible to post a review using Yelp API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried using Yelp API to do that, and at that moment was not supported.  Just checked its documentation: [Yelp API](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation), and it is not supported yet.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation):

> Users of the Yelp APIs will be able
>   to:
>
> - retrieve business review and rating information for a particular
>     geographic region or location.
> - display review information for a particular business.
> - determine accurate neighborhood name information for a particular location.
> - track recent reviews for a particular business.
> - display pictures of highly rated local businesses and of the top
>     reviewers for that business.
> - determine a particular business' review and rating information based on
>     the phone number for that business.

So, no, currently it is not possible to post reviews using the Yelp API.